# how can i resolve end of central dictionary error

Tags: visual-studio-2019

What causes this error and how can I resolve this error please?

`Number of entries expected in End Of Central Directory does not correspond to number of entries in Central Directory.`

Comment: lack of tags because i don't know the issue

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had a corrupt nuget package. I replaced this nuget package and everything worked again.